# Creat new column and calculate each element with conditions in r

Tags: r, loops, calculated-columns

I have a data frame (df) looks like this,

```
a    b    c
12   14   21
71   23   58
20   33   64
3    22   12
25   55   19
31   14   20
29   20   31
10   10   41
20   37   33
31   99   43
42   24   34
```

each element has no pattern in this data frame.

```
list<-c(1,3,5)
```

My current code is

```
df$d<-NA

  for (i in 1:length(list)){
      for( j in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$d[j]<- df$c[j]- df$b[j+i]
  print(mean(df$d, na.rm=TRUE))
}
}
```

For each element in "list", i loop it and calculate the mean(df$d), and then ask it to loop it again, then find the mean(df$d) again.

Expected result:

when i=1

```
a    b    c    d
12   14   21   -2 (=21-23)
71   23   58   25 (=58-33)
20   33   64   42   
3    22   12   -43
25   55   19    5
31   14   20    0
29   20   31   21
10   10   41    4
20   37   33   -66
31   99   43   19
42   24   34   NA
```

Then, find the mean of column "d", which is (mean(df$d, na.rm=TRUE), which is 5/10rows =0.5, this is mean is really what i need.

when i=3

```
a    b    c    d
12   14   21   -1 (=21-22)
71   23   58   3 (=58-55)
20   33   64   50   
3    22   12   -8
25   55   19    9
31   14   20    -17
29   20   31   -68
10   10   41    17
20   37   33   NA
31   99   43   NA
42   24   34   NA
```

Then, find the mean of column "d", which is (mean(df$d, na.rm=TRUE), which is -15/8rows =-1.875, this mean-value is really what i need.

This code is very slow since it has two loops running, the whole data has more than 50K rows, and the true list has more than 15 elements, so it takes forever. Would someone please help me on this, thank you so very much.

Comment: i just edit it, added some expected results for the first 2 loop over i in "list", i hope that helps, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over each element in `list` using `sapply`. We use `lead` from `dplyr` to get the leading values of `b` and subtract it from `c` column and then calculate the `mean` of it removing the `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)
sapply(list, function(x) mean(df$c - lead(df$b, x), na.rm = T))

#[1]  0.500000 -1.875000 -1.666667
```